# Calling controller from a router in Node.js: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Can somebody help me with my code, please? I'm trying to call a controller from my router.
The user submits a form, after that the router should call the controller. But it logs this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined.

So in the end there isn't a faculty saved to the database.

Where's the problem? I'm trying to fix it for like an hour already. By the way, I deleted the non-important stuff from the code below.

```
// app.js
app.use('/faculties', require('./routes/faculties'));

// faculties.js router
const { faculties } = require('./controllers/faculties');
router.post('/new-faculty', faculties.save, ensureAuthenticated)

//faculties.js controller
const Faculty = require('../models/faculty.js');
exports.save = (req, res) => {
faculty.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message
        })
    })
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `const faculty = require('../models/faculty.js');`: `f` should be small

Comment: @aRvi Thanks for comment. My question was kinda poorly written. Actually the main problem was when requiring the controller. Removing destructuring assignment {} fixed it. Now it just throws some other error in the console haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the main problem was when requiring the controller. Removing destructuring assignment {} fixed it.